# Asynchronous service call while starting the activity in android

Tags: android

I am starting an activity from one by passing some data in the intent. I want the next activity to call some asynchronous service (rest service) with the data from intent and show the result on screen.

I made the asynchronous call by starting a different thread from onStartup method. But this is failing with below error:

```
: INFO/ProductAdvertisingAPIOperation(290): done requesting and parsing
: WARN/ActivityManager(73): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
: INFO/Process(290): Sending signal. PID: 290 SIG: 9
: INFO/WindowManager(73): WIN DEATH: Window{43f64a28 com.zzzz.android.xxxx.main/com.zzzz.android.xxxx.main.HomeScreen paused=false}
: INFO/WindowManager(73): WIN DEATH: Window{43ffe9b8 com.zzzz.android.xxxx.main/com.zzzz.android.xxxx.main.CameraView paused=false}
: INFO/UsageStats(73): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.zzzz.android.xxxx.main
: WARN/InputManagerService(73): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 290 uid 10034
```

Does anybody know  the reason?
Thanks

Comment: I have used the async call as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493003/android-asynchronous-service-calls-strategy
>> just a thread (no service, since i don't need to expose it to other applications) w/ callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to not start the aysnc call in onCreate/onResume/OnStartup. Seems Android has some timeout for UI thread for 5 seconds, beyond which it throws 'Application Not Responding' message. In my case it was failing to load since this was happening on activity startup. So I am calling the async call afte rthe activity is started, onButtonclicked.

Thanks
Nayn